# Conditionally count rows based on month and value of a column

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing Airbnb listings. I want to count the number of listings for each host_id based on if they are Entire home or Shared home per month. Therefor I assume I need two additional columns with the count for each row (tot_EH and tot_SH).

I've posted an image below to show how the dataset looks like and the desired output (deleted some columns that are not relevant). Now I just used one host_id but in reality it's many different ones.

Marked the new columns in red and entered the desired output. Can't figure out how to proceed. Would really appreciate some help!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work and I got this error message:
Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate

Sorry if I didn't phrase my question right. Found a way to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Got help from a colleague and this worked:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(host_id, last_scraped) %>% # group data by host and month
  mutate(count_listings_in_data = length(unique(id)), # for each host/month combination; count the number of unique listing IDs
         count_shared_homes = length(unique(id[which(room_type_NV == "Shared home")])), # for each host/month combination; count the number of unique listing IDs for which the room type is "shared" 
         count_entire_homes = length(unique(id[which(room_type_NV == "Entire home")]))) # for each host/month combination; count the number of unique listing IDs for which the room type is "entire"
```

Answer (score 0):

One data.table approach, assuming your data are in a data.frame named df

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[room_type_NV == "Entire Home" , tot_EH := .N, by=.(date, host_id)]
df[room_type_NV == "Shared Home" , tot_SH := .N, by=.(date, host_id)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
df$grouping_var <- paste(df$host_id, as.Date(df$date, "%m-%Y"), sep = "_")

count_df <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$grouping_var),

                   function(x){

                     tmp <- data.frame(t(tapply(x$room_type_NV, x$room_type_NV, length)))

                     return(cbind(x, data.frame(tmp[rep(seq_len(nrow(tmp)), nrow(x)), ], row.names = NULL)))

                    }

                   )

                  ),

            row.names = NULL

             )
```

Data:

```
    structure(list(id = c(2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2), date = structure(c(16983, 
16983, 16983, 17014, 17014, 17014, 17045, 17045, 17106, 17106
), class = "Date"), host_id = c(27280608, 27280608, 27280608, 
27280608, 27280608, 27280608, 27280608, 27280608, 27280608, 27280608
), room_type_NV = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("Entire home", "Shared home"), class = "factor"), 
    grouping_var = c("27280608_2016-07-01", "27280608_2016-07-01", 
    "27280608_2016-07-01", "27280608_2016-08-01", "27280608_2016-08-01", 
    "27280608_2016-08-01", "27280608_2016-09-01", "27280608_2016-09-01", 
    "27280608_2016-11-01", "27280608_2016-11-01")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```